# Mocking a web service that relies on another service layer

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Tried to search for a solution, but maybe I couldn't form my question right for a useful result.

I would like to know if there are techniques to mock a (web) service that relies on a black box for its own logic that I have no knowledge of or control over.

Take payment gateways as an example. How do I mock a payment for testing where I want to simulate a payment that fails on the bank's level which is above the gateway's level (the service I'm calling)? 
For example the card is declined or some other card related failure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) in your code that deals with the external service. You can than mock that facade.

Your facade will be a thin layer that exposes only the methods from the external service that you're interested in and performs any necessary mappings between external service types and your internal model.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **IOC**.

use the Interface of the service in your code, and get an instance of the "service" using **MEF** or other framework. in the configuration, you will be able to choose witch implementation you want : the real or your mock (implementing this interface).